# How to eliminate background network activity on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, security, internet, network-traffic

I am running Windows 8.1 .  I want to configure my machine so that the only network activity that happens on my machine is the activity that I explicitly trigger (e.g. web requests made with a browser).  I want to disable features like live tiles, scanning for automatic updates, OneDrive data synchronization and any other process that involves my computer talking to some other device over a network without my explicit knowledge that the process is taking place.

What steps do I need to take in order to accomplish this?  Is there some place (or some places) that I can globally disable such OS features or do I need to do this with some external utility (e.g. NetBalancer)?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to disconnect the network.

If you don't like live tiles, uninstall all of the universal apps that provide them (you will need to complete this using PowerShell as some cannot be uninstalled by hand).

OneDrive is optional so remove it. Automatic updates can also be turned off though that may leave you vulnerable to malware unless you are very vigilant.

You can also set your network connection to be "metered" which cuts down the network chatter.

But there is much still going on around the network that you cannot easily stop since Windows is looking for other computers and services regularly.

Comment: I still need internet access. I just want it to be explicit.  Also, the components I listed are an arbitrary subset.  My goal is to target all network activity.

Comment: You cannot stop "everything" without also stopping the Internet. Make the connection metered to reduce traffic then uninstall unwanted applications. That's it. Windows has lots that it needs to do in the background & you don't get to micromanage it. As an alternative, switch to Linux where you will be given a lot more control but will have to do a lot more work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I wasn't in such debacle since windows XP, but I managed quite successfully to do just that back then. It's not a priority now, as im on unlimited mobile internet, but when I was travelling around Europe it was essential to give access to specific programs only. XP is nice for exactly that.

Windows 8 not so much. There may be a third-party firewall/internet connection manager that will help you do that, however. I was fond of NetLimiter and I see it supports Win8. Maybe that's the way to go? It will take a while to set up (especially at first), and that way you can just disable it when tight connection control is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the service called Network Connection Broker Service will stop the connections from tiles to microsoft's servers.  Right click on the windows icon in desktop (top left), go to computer management, select services, find the Network Connection Broker, stop and disable.